# Freezing form URL in Django

Tags: django, forms

I have a **message** app that users can read and replay messages.
The replay form message address (action) is look like this: **/messages/inbox/**
For example : **/messages/inbox/4**

```
<form method="post" action="/messages/inbox/4">{% csrf_token %}
...
</form>
```

And user can replay message. But user can change the address of form (action) to **/messages/inbox/6** for example.
and it will save the replay message to message_id=6.
It never make problem for me , because I check the user details before saving.
But I'm looking for a way to check if the form action changed , the system shows errors to the users after the post.

So how to freezing URL of form (action) in Django?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already doing the correct thing, which is to check the user's credentials in your view function before saving.

There is no way to stop malicious users from posting any data to any url they choose to... you have to ensure that your views which receive post data only perform legal actions.

Comment: you are right , but if the rows are 4,5,6,7 that user has access on them , it can save the message_id=4 on message_id=6. so it never make problem?

Comment: there's no way to prevent that, your main concern in that case has to be in your UI: to prevent a well-behaved user for doing the wrong thing accidentally when following the normal flow of your application. You can't prevent a badly-behaved user from doing anything they have privilege to do.